# PHP - redirect to the page of the newly added item?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, concept

How would I redirect to the page of the newly added item?

For example, I have 5 page list of items. After I successfully added a new item, I want it to redirect to the page where it should be located.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: In general you would get the last insert id and then get the url of the newly added item in whatever way you store it and then you can use it to header redirect.

Comment: are you using laravel?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController
{

    ...

    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        // do validation, etc...

        $post = Post::create($input);

        return Redirect::to("/posts/{$post->id}/detail");
    }

    ...

}
```

`Post` is Eloquent model here. `create` method stores data in database and return newly created object, which is assigned back to `$post` variable. All it's properties are accessible from this point.